# Should user chat message be an aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design, modeling

When modeling a typical chat application (with infinite chats), should each message be treated as an aggregate instance?

Aggregates should be kept small, and can not think of some other decent and small candidate to contain user messages. But at the same time, I just wonder I should use an aggregate concept for such a small object of the system.

Comment: DDD is a pattern applied to complex solutions which involve business rules. A chat application doesn't sound like a complex application where you'd get a lot of additional value by applying DDD. Not every type of application is suitable for DDD, i.e. simple CRUD services which basically dump the database and write directly to it with little or no logic at all (other than input validation)

Comment: Well, still, I'm pretty sure that there should be messaging apps that use DDD principles for modeling architecture.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on that. What kind of business **process** does a chat application represent? DDD is about transferring the business process into a software. If you are some kind of chat service provider, there may be some business logic involved in creating, billing and managing chat services (i.e. to sell it as a service to companies), but for sending the messages itself, don't think that would ever be an aggregate. Sending/obtaining messages may be a domain service (to validate the permissions or perform billing), but not an aggregate since a message itself has no business logic.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. But if there some capabilities like editing messages, and there are roles like old messages can not be edited, etc?

Comment: _When a significant process or transformation in the domain is not a natural responsibility of an ENTITY or VALUE OBJECT, add an operation to the model as standalone interface declared as a SERVICE. Define the interface in terms of the language of the model and make sure the operation name is part of the UBIQUITOUS LANGUAGE. Make the SERVICE stateless._ - from "Domain Driven Design" by Eric Evans. **TL;DR**: You do these kind of checks in the domain service which is responsible for doing the editing.

Comment: Thanks, will think about it -)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should each message be treated as an aggregate instance?

This is a good question, but asked to wrong group of people, as we don't know your business :)

> Aggregate is a synonym for the boundary of a transactional
>   consistency. [...] Properly designed Aggregate is the one, that can be
>   modified in the way business needs to modify it, while providing
>   business rules to be consistent as part of a single transaction. [...]
>   Aggregates are mostly about consistency boundaries, and their design
>   should not controlled by the need to create object graphs. [...] ~ Implementing Domain-Driven Design, Vaughn Vernon

Aggregates are mostly about transactional consistency in business rules. You should ask business if there are any rules regarding a single chat message. In a typical chat application probably not, but you have to ask business.

In a **simplest** chat application I can imagine, **my** chat message would rather be a Value Object. Or I would **not even use DDD** as Tseng mentioned. I can't think of any business rules I would need and it would definitly be immutable.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. What about the editing of messages?

Comment: Editing/Update is part of a simple CRUD. But if there are rules like when and why you can edit, you could go on with an aggregate. If this is the only business rule in your system, as I said, I would rather not use DDD, but if you are learning or you know it will change soon, go on.