# Best practice on determining an aggregate root vs child entities (DDD Modelling)

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I am attempting to model a set of entities and am seeking best practices on determining if a domain object is a candidate for an aggregate root or as a list of child entities under another aggregate root.

I have a `Game` object that represents a played game of a generic sport. The `Game` aggregate currently has a list of child entities titled `GamePlayers`. These `GamePlayer` entities also have a list of child entities titled `GamePlayerHits` which record where a player was hit during a game of this generic sport.

Methods exist on the `Game` aggregate such as `AddPlayer()` and `RemovePlayer()`. The child entities under `GamePlayer` of type `GamePlayerHit` also have methods such as `AddHit()`.

The problem I'm facing is whether `GamePlayers` should be an aggregate root of its own with a reference to the `Game` entity. A `Game` can technically exist without a list of `GamePlayers` initially, at some later stage it may get populated. The `Game` could also be deleted or cancelled without any players ever being registered. This leads me to believe that `GamePlayers` should be it's own aggregate based on examples I've see online.

This is the example where I began to question the best practices surrounding this subject:

https://github.com/kgrzybek/modular-monolith-with-ddd

Here, the `Meetings` aggregate has a list of child `MeetingAttendee` entities however the Meetings commenting feature `MeetingComment` is it's own aggregate with a reference back to the `Meeting` it belongs to. For ease of referencing:

[The Meeting class with MeetingAttendee child entities](https://github.com/kgrzybek/modular-monolith-with-ddd/blob/master/src/Modules/Meetings/Domain/Meetings/Meeting.cs)

[The MeetingComment class as it's own aggregrate](https://github.com/kgrzybek/modular-monolith-with-ddd/blob/master/src/Modules/Meetings/Domain/MeetingComments/MeetingComment.cs)

In this example why is `MeetingComment` not a list of child entities under the `Meeting` aggregate with a suitable `AddComment()` and `DeleteComment()` methods on the main aggregate? My assumption is either comments are optional and are not required to validate the aggregrate and/or these entities need referencing elsewhere via an identifier/key which wouldn't be possible as being a member of a child collection.

How does one determine taking in to account my example above regarding games which is the correct way to models these aggregates and entities? What determines if entities should exist as child entities or as a separate aggregate root?

Comment: Maybe this one can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57723675/1319086
tldr; Seek for business rules instead of groups of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does one determine taking in to account my example above regarding games which is the correct way to models these aggregates and entities? What determines if entities should exist as child entities or as a separate aggregate root?

The existence of a domain constraints connecting information.

If all we needed was to capture a bunch of information provided to us, we wouldn't need a *domain model*; a database is more than adequate for data capture.

We introduce the domain model because either (a) we need to ensure that new information is compatible with information that we have already captured and/or (b) there are derived values that we want to compute locally (ex: because computing them locally reduces the error rate).

Rule: If we have a constraint that must *always* hold, and that constraint spans multiple pieces of information, then that information must all be contained within a single "aggregate".

The justification for the rule: information subject to a constraint like this must be changed [atomically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity).  In other words, we want all of this information to be part of a single unit for the purpose of data changes.  Therefore, the domain entities that manage this information must all be part of the same "aggregate".

In the cargo shipping example taken from the blue book (Evans, 2003), we have a constraint on the misdirected property of a shipment: it must be true if the most recently recorded handling event for a container is inconsistent with the most recently assigned itinerary.  It follows that these three pieces of information must be stored atomically (otherwise we risk inconsistencies in our stored data), and therefore that the domain entities that manage this information must all be part of the same aggregate.

I tend to imagine a graph - the data are nodes, and each constraint implies edges connecting the data subject to that constraint.  Our rule then becomes "every graph must be contained entirely within a single aggregate".

A single aggregate *can* contain more than one of these graphs, but in doing that you are also introducing contention that is *not* inherent to the domain -- this is one of the forms of "accidental complexity".